# Multiply arrays in a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of arrays with the same shape, like this:

```
my_list = [arr_1, arr_2, arr_3, ...]

arr_1.shape
(1988, 1221)
...
```

Is there a way to multiply every array in my list and get a final array with the same shape?

I've tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
for i in my_list:
    arr_final = np.multiply(my_list[i])
```

The final array should be the same of every array in the initial list.

```
arr_final.shape
(1988, 1221)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack them and take product:

```
mylist = [np.array([1,2]), np.array([2,3]), np.array([1,4])]


np.stack(mylist).prod(0)
```

Output:

```
array([ 2, 24])
```